# Як назвати людину, що має науковий ступінь?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Виникла потреба сказати про людину, що здобула науковий ступінь, не уточнюючи, кандидат вона чи доктор. За пошуком Гугла, використовують словосполучення [володар наукового ступеня](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%22) (83 результати), [власник наукового ступеня](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%22) (8 результатів), але звучить якось кострубато. Володар за [семантикою](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15718&page=521) ближчий до очільника, наділеного владою. [Власник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15171&page=498) стосується перш за все матеріального майна. Чи є якийсь сталий вираз для цього випадку або яка назва була б більш доречною?

Answer (score 1):

Можна сказати ["*науковець зі ступенем*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D1%96+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%22) або ["*науковий працівник зі ступенем*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D1%96+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%22). Хоча й такі сполуки слів менше використовують, але, по-моєму, це те, що ви хочете сказати, не вживаючи "власник" чи "володар".

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.

Comment: bytebuster сказав: «Хоча теоретично це може дати відповідь на запитання, було б краще надати посилання на надійні джерела та / або наукові дослідження. Непідкріплені дописи привертають „мінуси“ і провокують диспути».

Comment: Я навіть не знаю, чи погоджуватися мені з bytebuster чи ні (з одного боку, відповідь справді виглядає незвично короткою і нічим не обґрунтованою, а з іншого — поради, дані в ній, вважаю дуже доречними). Але по-моєму, Ви задовольните всі сторони, якщо просто наведете **пару прикладів використання** запропонованих Вами формулювань у якихось джерелах (чим серйозніші джерела, тим краще).